# iOS: measure download speed with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I use AFDownloadRequestOperation to download file. I want to show download speed to user. I guess the method 
`- (void)setDownloadProgressBlock:(void (^)(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead))block;`
maybe has some help. But no download time is provided in block. So I don't know how to calculate speed with this method.

Comment: Save a date object before the the download starts that is accessible from inside the block and use it to check the elapsed time (using timeIntervalSinceDate).